# Can't display ajax success response message in an html format in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a website with `WordPress` using `Elementor` plugin and I am looking to display different pages with `AJAX` without refreshing.
The `php` part inside the `functions.php` looks like the following :

```
function my_action(){
    if(is_page($_POST['post'])){
        wp_enqueue_script('mon_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/mon_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    }
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];

    if(!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'ajax_nonce')){
        die('Interdit!');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['param'])){
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'type' => 'post', 'page_id' => $_POST['param'] ) );
        //var_dump($query);

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
            $query->the_post();

            get_template_part('template-parts/content-page', get_post_format());

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.

        wp_reset_postdata();

    }else{
        exit;
    }
    die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_my_action", "my_action");

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action", "my_action");

wp_enqueue_script('mon_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/mon_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

wp_localize_script('mon_script', 'mon_ajax_variable', array(
'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax_nonce')
)
);
```

I just took my theme-premade `template` in order to just replace its content by a different page each time I choose to do so (clicking on a different menu item in my case).

My `jQuery` part looks like this :

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu-item-416").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type : 'post',
                url : mon_ajax_variable.url,
                data : {
                    action : 'my_action',
                    nonce : mon_ajax_variable.nonce,
                    param : 57
                },
                dataType : 'text',
                success : function(response){
                    alert(response);
                    jQuery("#primary").html(response).show();
                },
                error : function(errorMsg){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

In fact, as WordPress always assigns a `unique id` to each page created, I just fetched the `id` of the page (here 57) I want to take the place of the current one `#primary element`.
When I checked, `AJAX` is returning the `success response` and the `alert method` pretty displays it in a `text/HTML` format but when I try to integrate it within the `#primary element` using `jQuery("#primary").html(response).show();`, I get a blank page. It's like the `HTML success response` doesn't want to be displayed as a child of the `#primary element`.

Could anyone show me what's wrong with what I've done?

I am posting the template codes if needed :

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package online_cv_resume
 */

?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( array('col-md-12','entry-single-content-wrp') ); ?>>


        <?php
            /**
            * Hook - online_cv_resume_posts_blog_media.
            *
            * @hooked online_cv_resume_posts_blog_media - 10
            * @hooked online_cv_resume_posts_blog_media - 20
            * @hooked online_cv_resume_posts_blog_loop_title - 20
            */
            do_action( 'online_cv_resume_posts_blog_media' );
        ?>
        <div class="entry-content blog-details">
       <?php
        the_content();

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'online-cv-resume' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
        ?>

        <?php if ( get_edit_post_link() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-edit">
            <?php
            edit_post_link(
                sprintf(
                    wp_kses(
                        /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                        __( 'Edit <span class="screen-reader-text">%s</span>', 'online-cv-resume' ),
                        array(
                            'span' => array(
                                'class' => array(),
                            ),
                        )
                    ),
                    get_the_title()
                ),
                '<span class="edit-link">',
                '</span>'
            );
            ?>
        </div ><!-- .entry-footer -->
    <?php endif; ?>
        </div>


</div>
<!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

I look forward to hearing from you coz' It has been days I am on it.

Thank you in advance for your replies,

Comment: I am not sure at the moment what is the issue in your network of browser are you getting 200 okay response? Also , try to do echo before get_template_part. I am not sure the above suggestion is just one silly idea. I am not sure about that suggestion at the correct moment.

Comment: When I do echo before get_template_part, it still  prints me blank page. I don't really know the response number, but it is supposed to return a set of HTML elements (HTML codes) in a string format. When I do the alert in jquery, it prints me the HTML codes but when I try to append it to the #primary element, I just get nothing displayed, it is just blank page. I think it is just a matter of displaying but I don't really know what's missing or what I should not have written.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into the following code. [Here is the code explainging it.](https://code.elementor.com/methods/elementor-frontend-get_builder_content_for_display/)

```
$pluginElementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
        $contentElementor = $pluginElementor->frontend->get_builder_content_for_display($post_ID,true);
        echo $contentElementor;
```